# Merge an item attribute of one array into items of another array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a few questions in regards to what would be the best approach to do the following:

1. Call two different API:

   ```
   axios.get(contents);
   axios.get(favorites);
   ```
2. Response will Look like this:

   ```
   contents: [
      {
          id: 1,
          value: someValue
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          value: someValue
      }
   ];

   favorites: [
       {
           id: 1,
           contentId: 2    
       }
   ];
   ```

What would be the best approach to loop through each favorite and add an element to the contens array such as `isFavorite: true` when the `contentId` matches the `id`. It should look as follows:

```
    contents: [
        {
            id: 1,
            value: someValue
        {,
        {
            id: 2,
            value: someValue
            isFavorite: true
        {
    ];
```

What would be the best place to do this and is there any ES6 syntax that can easily do this? I currently have the two actions separate, one that gets the contents and one that gets the favorites, I could possibly merge those or combine them at the reducer.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to collect all `contentId` values from `favorites` and then iterate through your `contents` array. This has better time complexity than using `some` on an array because calling `.has()` on a `Set` is *O(1)*:

```js
let contents = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'someValue1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'someValue2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: 'someValue'
  }
];

let favorites = [{
    id: 1,
    contentId: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    contentId: 3
  }
];

let favoriteContents = new Set(favorites.map(f => f.contentId));
contents.forEach(c => {
  if (favoriteContents.has(c.id)) c.isFavorite = true;
});
console.log(contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const newContents = contents.map((content) => {
   const foundFavorite = favorites.find((favorite) => favorite.contentId === content.id)
   if (foundFavorite) {
      return {
         ...content,
         isFavorite: true,
      }
   }
   return content
});
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to have the promises from your API calls, and when both of them are complete you can then carry out the merge of the results.

```
const contentsApi = () => Promise.resolve([
   {
       id: 1,
       value: 'foo'
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       value: 'bar'
   }
])

const favouritesApi = () => Promise.resolve([
    {
        id: 1,
        contentId: 2    
    }
])

let contents;
let favourites;

const contentsApiCall = contentsApi().then(res => {
    contents = res;
})

const favouritesApiCall = favouritesApi().then(res => {
  favourites = res;
})



Promise.all([contentsApiCall, favouritesApiCall]).then(() => {
    const merged = contents.map(content => {
    if(favourites.some(favourite => favourite.contentId === content.id)){
        return {
        ...content,
        isFavourite: true
      }
    } else {
        return content;
    }
  })
  console.log(merged)
  // do whatever you need to do with your result, either return it if you want to chain promises, or set it in a variable, etc.
})
```